# Java Duration between exception

Tags: java, time, java-8

I use the java Duration between method to calcul a duration between to a LocalTime and LocalDateTime it's work when I put the localTime as the first argument of the method but when I reversed the order it gave an exception DateTimeException :

This work fine :

```
 LocalTime t1 = LocalTime.now();
 LocalDateTime t2 = LocalDateTime.now();
 System.out.println(Duration.between(t1, t2));
```

When I reversed the agrs it gave me an exception :

```
 LocalTime t1 = LocalTime.now();
 LocalDateTime t2 = LocalDateTime.now();
 System.out.println(Duration.between(t2, t1));

Exception in thread "main" java.time.DateTimeException: Unable to obtain LocalDateTime from TemporalAccessor: 16:32:18.553 of type java.time.LocalTime
```

can someone explain why I get this exception thanks for any help :=)

Comment: What should the answer be if I ask you how much time there is between the 19 sep. 2019 at 12:00 and 09:12:34? My answer would be: 09:12:34 of which day?And that's also the answer that Duration.between provides.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the docs:  [Duration between](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html#between-java.time.temporal.Temporal-java.time.temporal.Temporal-)

> If the objects are of different types, then the duration is calculated based on the type of the first object. For example, if the first argument is a LocalTime then the second argument is converted to a LocalTime.

So basically, the error is thrown because you can't cast a LocalTime object into a LocalDateTime, the date information is not included in the LocalTime.

Comment: It is like unable to obtain LocalDate from java.time.LocalTime because LocalTime doesn't have LocalDate.